# Javascript array problem

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var data = [];
var id = 23;
var num = 12;
var dog_trialset = 15;
var cat_trialset = 23;
```

problem  from here

```
data.push({id:{num:num, dog_trialset:dog_trialset, cat_trialset:cat_trialset}});
```

ajax post to php

```
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => Array
                    (
                        [num] => 12
                        [dog_trialset] => 15
                        [cat_trialset] => 34
                    )

            )

    )
```

I want `[id] => Array(...)` to `[23] => Array(...)`;

Thanks

Comment: i dont understand your question.

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy: The OP is using the identifier `id` in the literal object, but expected to use the value of the variable `id` as identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable as the key using the subscript operator:

```
var row = {};
row[id] = {num:num,dog_trialset:dog_trialset,cat_trialset:cat_trialset};
data.push(row);
```